# Jcrop not showing image when using a background-color in the div

Tags: javascript, html, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop (Jcrop.com). Everything works fine if my `div` doesn't have any `background-color`. However, if I add a `background-color` (see the fiddle where `background-color: blue;`), then the image does not display anymore. The area can still be selected by Jcrop but everything appears blue. Can someone help please? thanks a lot.
Fiddle: (try to remove the `background-color` and see that it works) https://jsfiddle.net/htxkwy43/1/

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.